# Run programs on wayland at default

Tags: wayland

I'm on Ubuntu 19.04. I have recently switched to 1080p display which caused everything to shrink down. And so I had to enable the experimental fractional scaling in Wayland. I chose to switch to Wayland because fractional scaling on xorg caused screen tearing. It seems however that many programs do not run natively on Wayland, which causes them to appear very blurry.

This can be fixed by running each program like this `GDK_BACKEND=wayland firefox`. However it's a bit cumbersome to have to open each program like that instead of using a visual icon. Is there a way to make programs like firefox, thunderbird, vlc run on wayland at default? Or automate this in any way?

Comment: take a look https://wiki.gnome.org/Initiatives/Wayland/SessionStart